# Why the javascript file in my vim dispear after running it?

Tags: javascript, vim

I have mapped F7 into running javascript function with the command :

```
map <F7> <Esc>:silent !firefox  %<cr>
```

I press F7 when to edit the javascript file in vim ,the js file can run and display the result in firefox browser properly,but strange things happened that the javascript file in vim dispear (can't be seen at all),how to make it displayed on my vim console again?

picture 1: vim  /var/www/test.html
[image]

picture 2: press F6 to open the test.html  in firefox,get the right output in firefox .
[image]

picture 3: the vim console  changed after to press F6 key.
[image]

picture 4: nothing on my vim window when to close the firefox window,the source javascipt file "/var/www/test.html" dispear!

[image]

The sourec file is simple as the following:

```
<html>
   <body>

      <script type="text/javascript">
         <!--
            var count;
            document.write("Starting Loop" + "<br />");

            for(count = 0; count < 10; count++){
               document.write("Current Count : " + count );
               document.write("<br />");
            }   

            document.write("Loop stopped!");
         //-->
      </script>

      <p>Set the variable to different value and then try...</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

I can cat  /var/www/test.html when to close the vim window,the test.html don't lose ,just can't be displayed  on the vim window!

Comment: What is happening with the file? Are you saying the file itself just disapears?

Comment: yes,i got right result in the firefox,but the source javascript file in my vim console can't be seen now.

Comment: I'm afraid I might be misunderstanding you, but what do you mean your vim "console"? Vim is a text editor, it doesn't have a built in console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to vim `:help :silent`:

> ":silent" will also avoid the hit-enter prompt. When using this for
>   an external command, this may cause the screen to be messed up. Use
>   CTRL-L to clean it up then.

That seems to be the problem.

This

```
nmap <F7> <ESC>:let ff_output=system('firefox ' . bufname("%"))<CR>
```

works for me without messing the screen.

Comment: it is a great command :  nmap <F7> <ESC>:let ff_output=system('firefox ' . bufname("%"))<CR>